# Copy a column of data from an Excel file to another file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file in which a column (total hours) is present.

As I update the `total hours` column I need those values to be reflected in another Excel file under a column (`Efforts`).

Can anyone give me the macro for the above said problem..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It might make life a lot easier to keep everything in one workbook using separate sheets instead of completely separate files. Then you can make use of HLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, and referencing ranges with the `Sheetname!Address` format (`Sheet1!A3:A4` for example)...

Answer (score 0):

It should still be possible to have cells that reference cells from another workbook.  I have done this with older versions of Excel.  This [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051995141033.aspx)  to the Microsoft site has instructions for 2003 version, but should still apply.